# Imports in Python using Flask

Tags: python, flask, import, python-import

I keep getting this error when trying to import my app and app.models.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tools.py", line 3, in 
from app import db
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

```
app/
   api/
      __init__.py
      users.py
      ...
   db_tools/
      __init__.py
      tools.py
   errors/
      __init__.py
      ...
   __init__.py
   models.py
```

app/db_tools/tools.py file:

```
import psycopg2
import os
from app import db
from app.models import UpdateLogs

...rest of code...

def request_update_log_comment():
    return input('Enter a comment for the update:\n')

def create_update_log_comment():
    comment = request_update_log_comment()
    update_logs = UpdateLogs()
    update_logs.save_log(comment)
    db.session.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_update_log_comment()
```

/db_tools/**init**.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('db_tools', __name__)

from app.db_tools import tools
```

I understand that there is no db.py file in app. However, all the other files in app/api and app/errors use this import without issue.
What gives? The app/db_tools folder is structured just like app/api and app/errors. Here's an example from api/users.py that works just fine. Notice that app/users.py is at the same file level as app/tools.py just in a different folder.

app/api/users.py

```
from flask import jsonify, request, url_for, abort
import ssl
import base64
import re
from app import db
from app.api import bp
from app.api.auth0 import AuthError, requires_auth
from app.api.errors import bad_request
from app.models import CustomNotes, SavedSets, ContactMessages

...rest of code...
```

app/**init**.py

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
import os
from config import Config
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_cors import CORS


db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
cors = CORS()


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    cors.init_app(app)


    from app.api import bp as api_bp
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

    from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)

    from app.db_tools import bp as db_tools_bp
    app.register_blueprint(db_tools_bp)

    if not app.debug and not app.testing:
        if app.config['LOG_TO_STDOUT']:
            stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            app.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

        else:
            if not os.path.exists('logs'):
                os.mkdir('logs')
            file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/website.log',
                                            maxBytes=10240, backupCount=10)
            file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
                '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
                '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
            file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        app.logger.info('Flask app startup')

    return app


from app import models
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be \_\_init\_\_.py?

Comment: @RyanJonZhang SO converted ithe dunders to bold formatting, since it was not within a literal text block.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get `db` from the app package, but there is nothing called `db`.
so your folder structure should include `db`

```
app/
   api/
      __init__.py
      ...
   db_tools/
      __init__.py
      tools.py
   errors/
      __init__.py
      ...
   __init__.py
   db.py     <----------------------------
   models.py
```

Now, if you want to get the object `db` created in `app/__init__`  (`db = SQLAlchemy()`) that is something different. For this, you will need to design the code in a different way.

Not sure what are you using in tool.py that required an object `db` so I cannot be more specific.

Comment: I added more details to my questions. I understand what you are saying but not having db.py directly under app hasn't been an issue in other files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `db` in `app` directory or in `app\__init__.py` so how can you import `db` from `app`? hence the error.

Comment: No. That shouldn't be the issue. All the other files in /api and /errors use the ```from app import db```. I'm assuming Flask somehow allows for this.